# React native with google sheets

Tags: react-native

I need to store the return in a variable to display in another component, I am only able to view the return in the console.log

```
const GoogleSpreadsheet = require ('google-spreadsheet')
const credentials = require('./src/credentials.json')
const { promisify } = require('util')

const docId = '1RPWKohhPnHwoH78wrU0VtSaW_zj91kW_oKrAdWktLjY'

const accessSheet = async() => {
  const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(docId)
  await promisify(doc.useServiceAccountAuth)(credentials)
  const info = await promisify(doc.getInfo)()
  const worksheet = info.worksheets[0]

// select row
  const rows = await promisify(worksheet.getRows)({
    query: 'imei = 121545465456'
  })
rows.forEach(row => {
  console.log(row.status)
})
}
accessSheet()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `store the return in a variable to display in another component`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: I want to query data in a google spreadsheet API and put the return in a variable to display in another react-native component. understood?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your goal from your replying. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this. But when I could correctly understand about your goal, I would like to think of the solution.